# javascript force play sound instead of download

Tags: javascript, html, mp3

I recently made a soundboard about **hearthstone**, but when I click on the **card(image)** on my localhost it plays the **sound(like intended)**, while when I click on the **card(image)** on my online hosting it downloads the file.

Is there a way to make sure it always plays the sound?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('.card').click(function(){
            $('#wrap').html('<embed id="embed_player" src="'+$(this).attr('name')+'" autostart="true" hidden="true"></embed>');
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="pictures">     
    <img name="media/Sir-finly.mp3" src="media/Sir finly.gif" class="card"       id="sir-finly" alt="" />
    <img name="media/ShifterZerus.mp3" src="media/ShifterZerus.gif"    class="card" id="shifterzerus" alt="" />
    <div id="wrap"></div>
</div>
```

hope you guys can help me.

Comment: is the server adding this header: `Content-Disposition: attachment`? it forces the download (contrary is `Content-Disposition: inline`. Just to be curious, why not use the `<audio>` tag?

Comment: It's not adding that for as far that I can see in the console. The reason that I'm using this instead of the audio tag, is because my teacher said this would work better when I was making this in the lesson where we learned things like JavaScript.

Comment: it is debatable, with `audio` you will be limited to HTML5 support, whereas `embed` seems to have been left over, and never really implemented in a unique standard way in the different browsers (but its support still exists). Never used `embed` so i can't be definitive about it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **audio** tag instead of **embed**.
Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxaLMO

**HTML**

```
<div id="pictures">     
<img name="http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).ogg" src="http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/8/178/256/numbers-1-filled-icon.png" class="card"       id="sir-finly" alt="" />
<img name="http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(2).ogg" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/number-2-two-icon-13.png"    class="card" id="shifterzerus" alt="" />
<audio id="player" src="" autoplay></audio>
```

**JS**

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
    $('.card').click(function(){
        $('#player').attr('src', $(this).attr('name'));
    });
});
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Comment: This does help with the fact that it doesn't download the file anymore, but my browser still won't play the file for some reason. Is it because I'm using opera or does it have to do something with the hosting or even the code?

Comment: @djquinn what version of opera do you use? 
You can see browser compatibility of audio tag [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio).

Try it in other browser. If it doesn't work, It may be problem of your hosting provider.

Comment: I tested the site in some different browsers right now, and the result is the same in every browser. I guess that the problem lies within my hosting, because it does work on my localhost.

Comment: @djquinn yes, write to the hosting support. Good luck!